# usrname for xampp's mysql

Tags: mysql

there is a database named mysql in my xampp's mysql rdbms.....there is a table in it named widget wwhich i wish to access in my php program.... i wrote:

```
mysql_connect('dbname=mysql user=xampp');
```

can u tell me what is the appropriate username.

Answer (score 0):

from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
 resource mysql_connect ([ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

use `root` as username. It is default username for wamp/xamp

Answer (score 0):

If it's not 'xampp' then it's going to be 'root'. Yet regardless you're using mysql_connect() wrong anyhow.

```
mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "" );
```

Will (or should) connect you using the default xampp setup.

Comment: ok.........but then how does the comp know which data base it is going to connect to....there are many databases in xamp....one of them being mysql....the same name as the rdbms.

Comment: [Easy](http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db). Run mysql_select_db("mysql") and then you're good.